# What is the syntax of filling graphic file in MDIForm use VB

Tags: vb6

I am working in Visual Basic. There is facility of filling graphic file in MDIForm through properties option in Visual Basic. But I want to fill it by coding.

I am using this syntax:

```
MDIForm.Picture = "D:\GraphicFoler\MyPic.jpg"
```

but it does not work properly.

Please guid me in this respect, I would be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `LoadPicture()`.

Example: `MDIForm.Picture = LoadPicture("D:\GraphicFoler\MyPic.jpg")`

If your picture resides in the same folder where your application(project) resides, then you could use it like this: `MDIForm.Picture = LoadPicture(App.path & "\MyPic.jpg")`